# Quartz : Dynamic job scheduling

Tags: java, dynamic, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I'm scheduling quartz job dynamically and one of the issue that I came across is, I couldnt find an option to programmatically set the job to "PersistJobDataAfterExecution" and "DisallowConcurrentExecution" as both are annotation. Can any of you please suggest whats the equivalent while scheduling a job programmatically ( not declarative )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are scheduling dynamically you should be passing a JobDetail to the Scheduler.  You should be able to create your own JobDetail implementation or extends the base implementation then return whatever you want for the corresponding methods.

Comment: That make sence. I wasnt sure whether Quartz is doing anything more than that with that annotations. Looking at the sourcode, the isXX methods are the one which uses those annotations and overriding alone would solve that issue. Thanks for your suggestion.